# Does it make sense to handle MySQL query fields as an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php object method that load object "A" with the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT A.foo, A.bar...
```

I have another php object named B that uses MySQL fields from object A:

```
SELECT A.foo, A.bar...
       B.abc, B.xyz
```

To prevent code repetition, would it be considered a good practice to create an array (or an object) that stores the MySQL fields names of Object A so that this array can be used in object A and object B, like this:

Object A MySQL loading:

```
SELECT '.implode(',', $mysql_a_fields).' '...
```

Object B MySQL loading:

```
SELECT '.implode(',', $mysql_a_fields).', 
        B.abc, B.xyz
```

Or would it be code smell?

The goal is to to prevent repeating some SQL fields along queries that use those SQL fields. For example,  if there is a mysql date field for object A that I want to get formatted the same way in all the requests I use this date field, is there any design pattern to prevent repeating DATE_FORMAT(date_field) in all the request?

Thank you

Comment: Smells janky to me.

Comment: But if there is a mysql date field for object A that I want to get formatted the same way in all the requests I use this date field, is there any design pattern to prevent repeating  DATE_FORMAT(date_field) in all the request? (just an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About that array of field names. I would not do it. If you need to write all your selects this way, than write them. I do not know enough about your class/project structure to say if this makes sense.

To help you with your date formatting problem (well, it's not really a problem, isn't it), I think you have two options:
1. Get the date field from the database as is and convert it in PHP. (Use a helper class that is accessible from everywhere to do this.)
2. Create a stored procedure that converts the format for you and use this in your SELECT queries.